# Define Grid Panel Layout Size style property

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I am trying to add a `TLabel`, `TButton`, `TEdit` and another `TButton` to a `TGridPanelLayout`. I was not sure if sizestyle auto was going to be the best or not so wanted to test it.  I make my components at runtime. So I am trying to add a new row for each SET of components.  But I cannot figure out how to set the property to auto for SizeStyle.  I currently have `GridpanelLayout1.RowCollection[i].SizeStyle := TsizeStyle.auto`
but it gives error that TSizeStyle is undeclared.

```
 //add to grid
      gridpanelLayout1.BeginUpdate;

      if i <> 0 then
      begin
      GridpanelLayout1.rowcollection.Add;
      GridpanelLayout1.RowCollection[i].SizeStyle := TsizeStyle.auto
      end;

      GridpanelLayout1.ControlCollection.Add;
      GridpanelLayout1.ControlCollection[i].Column := 0;
      GridpanelLayout1.controlCollection[i].Row := i;
      GridpanelLayout1.ControlCollection[i].Control := (namelabel);

      GridpanelLayout1.ControlCollection.Add;
      GridpanelLayout1.ControlCollection[i].Column := 1;
      GridpanelLayout1.controlCollection[i].Row := i;
      GridpanelLayout1.ControlCollection[i].Control := (minusButton);

      GridpanelLayout1.ControlCollection.Add;
      GridpanelLayout1.ControlCollection[i].Column := 2;
      GridpanelLayout1.controlCollection[i].Row := i;
      GridpanelLayout1.ControlCollection[i].Control := (editfield);

      GridpanelLayout1.ControlCollection.Add;
      GridpanelLayout1.ControlCollection[i].Column := 3;
      GridpanelLayout1.controlCollection[i].Row := i;
      GridpanelLayout1.ControlCollection[i].Control := (Plusbutton);

      GridpanelLayout1.EndUpdate;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TSizeStyle` is a type declared *within* the `TGridPanelLayout` class.

To fix the problem, change that line to read

```
GridpanelLayout1.RowCollection[i].SizeStyle := TGridPanelLayout.TsizeStyle.auto
```